# React typescript reusable component with different types of data in same prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics

I need to render four charts. Datatype for charts are different. For example,

```
interface dataA{
    name: string,
    amount: number
}

interface dataB{
    title: string,
    amount: number
}

interface dataC{
    author: string,
    amount: number
}

interface dataB{
    country: string,
    amount: number
}
```

I am trying to create a reusable component which can render for all these different data types.

My approach currently consists,
Parent Component,

```
<DashboardChartCard
    cardTitle="users"
    dataset={userData}
/>
<DashboardChartCard
    cardTitle="Books"
    dataset={bookData}
/>
<DashboardChartCard
    cardTitle="Authors"
    dataset={authorData}
/>
<DashboardChartCard
    cardTitle="Countries"
    dataset={countryData}
/>
```

In DashboardChartCard component,

```
type PropsType<T> = {
  cardTitle: string;
  dataset: T[];
};

const DashboardChartCard = <T,>({
  cardTitle,
  dataset = [],
  currencies,
}: PropsType<T>) => {
}
```

So far it doesn't show any error in ts. But for chart I need to create two different array of `labels` and `data`. For data, I need the amount field. For labels I need to access different keys. I am not sure how can I access these fields from my component to create these two new `labels` and `data` array. What should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

The technique you are looking for is called [Narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html). It allows you to determine and perform a process of elimination based on if statements.

```js
// 1. Create a type that groups all of your data types together
type dataAny =  (dataA | dataB | dataC | dataD);

// mock data
const array: dataAny[] = [{author: "Author", amount: 1}, {country: "Country", amount: 2}];

// 2. Write a function that determines what type it is using the "in" keyword
function getLabelFromData(data: dataAny): string | undefined {
  if ("name" in data) {
    return data.name; // dataA
  } else if ("title" in data) {
    return data.title; // dataB
  } else if ("author" in data) {
    return data.author; // dataC
  } else if ("country" in data) {
    return data.country; // dataD
  }
  return undefined;
}

// 3. Use it in your component:
type PropsType = {
  cardTitle: string;
  dataset: dataAny[]; // 4. set dataset to your union type
};

function DashboardChartCard({
  cardTitle,
  dataset = [],
  currencies,
}: PropsType<T>) => {
   // 5. call getLabelFromData to extract the information you want.
}
```